# Subversion: Change all static externals from operative to peg revisions?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-externals

We have some shared libraries, and these are referenced as static externals in all tagged versions of our different projects.

After reorganizing the directory structure of our shared libraries, I see that all tagged versions now gives an error. I realised that the externals should have been referenced by using peg revision (@X) instead of operative revision (-r X).

We have hundreds of tagged versions, and inside these there are two-three different external references.

How can I recursively change the external definitions from operative to peg in my /main/projectX/tags/ folders? I imagine I will need some sort of shell script to do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this by running:

```
svn propget svn:externals -R http://repoURL
```

The output was used as a starting point for creating a svnmucc control file with the following content:

```
propset
svn:externals
^/external-source external-target
http://repoURL
propset
svn:externals
^/external-source2 external-target2
http://repoURL
```

And this was applied to the repo by running:

```
svnmucc -m 'Changing externals from operative to peg' -X controlfile.txt
```

The output of propget was quite different from the svnmucc format, so I had to do some manual work, and wrote a little PHP script to do most of the repetative work.

The only thing I was not able to do using svnmucc, was multiple externals on the same folder. Apparently, svnmucc [cannot set multi-line properties on the same target](http://subversion.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=462&dsMessageId=2371714). But we only had a few of those in our repo, so that was OK to fix manually using the TortoiceSVN repo browser.